# Questions about Poincaré–Bendixson theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

I just finished reading [Schwartz's article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373135) on the generalization of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem to compact two-dimensional manifolds. Which says:

*Let $M$ be a two-dimensional differentiable manifold of class $C^2$ compact and connected. Let $\varphi: \mathbb R \times M \to M$ be a flow of class $C^2$ in $M$. A minimal set $\mu\subset M$ can be either:*

1. *a singular point, or*
2. *a periodic orbit, or*
3. *an entire manifold $M$ which is homeomorphic to the torus $T^2$.*

But a few questions popped into my head that I couldn't answer:

1. Do you know any references where I can find the proof of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem in the projective plane $\mathbb P^2$?
2. What happens to $\mathbb P^3$?
3. Does anyone know any example of dimension 3 that is under the conditions of Schwartz's theorem whose omega limit is different from a singular point, a closed orbit and the torus?
4. Do you know any differentiable manifold of dimension greater than two where the flow is interesting to study? That is to say, some variety in which it is possible to attempt some sort of smooth generalization of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem?
5. I was quite impressed with the $C^2$ class flows in the torus. Does anyone know what happens to $C^2$ flows in the $2-$torus? or in the $n-$torus?

I know there are a lot of questions and I'm sure they'll get my attention because of that, but all the questions are closely related to the same topic and I didn't want to create too many separate questions because there might be some future readers wondering the same thing. I hope you can help me clear these doubts and continue learning.

Comment: What is a *stream*, and in particular what is the difference between a *flow* and a *stream* in question 5?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I got distracted and put something else. But I already corrected it, I was referring at all times to a flow.

Comment: I notice that the statement of the theorem does not mention orientability. Is there any other reason why it does not therefore apply directly to  the projective plane?

Comment: Indeed, Schwartz's theorem includes this case, but I was wondering if there is an independent proof in a simpler way since the case addressed by this theorem is much broader.